# Запятая как-то(,) да?

Tags: пунктуация, грамотная-речь, запятые

Нужна ли запятая перед "да"?

Знаешь, Василий, надоела мне уже эта чёрная полоса - охота **как-то(,) да** поменять свою жизнь, выйти замуж, родить детей...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Не нужна запятая:**

*Знаешь, Василий, надоела мне уже эта чёрная полоса - охота **как-то да** поменять свою жизнь, выйти замуж, родить детей...*

**Пояснение**

Частицу ***ДА*** можно **убрать** из предложения, при этом семантика и постановка знаков **не изменится.**

[**ДА, частица.**](https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=%D0%B4%D0%B0&mode=slovari&dicts%5B%5D=42) 8. (в начале предл. или внутри его перед сказ., группой сказ.). Употр. для придания высказыванию **большей силы, выразительности.** И я чего-нибудь да стою! Да что с вами говорить! Да так оно обычно и бывает. Да кто вы такой, чтоб так задаваться? Да тебе-то что за дело? Куда идти? - Да прямо!

Примеры **с частицей ДА:**

```
  К чему только это все.
  Если решил молчать,
  Может тогда решить,
  И что то да поменять.
```

**Игорь Куншенко. Дни лукавы // «Ковчег», 2015**

*Сене казалось, что от падения он свернулся в клубок, словно ежик, а вот понять, как развернуться, так и не мог. Конечно, со временем **как-то да** развернулся. Время — оно такое: бесконечное, безликое, бесчеловечное.*